# (Java) Is there a way to create a variable in a method and change the name of the variable each time?

Tags: java

I have a Word class that stores name, part of speech, and definition:

```
public class Word{
    String name;
    String partOfSpeech;
    String definition;

    public Word(String s1, String s2, String s3){
        name = s1;
        partOfSpeech = s2;
        definition = s3;
    }
}
```

In another file, I have a method that creates a new Word

```
public static void addWord(Scanner userInput) {
        System.out.print("Enter word:");
        String word = userInput.next();
        System.out.print("Enter the part of speech of " + word + ": ");
        String POS = userInput.next();
        System.out.print("Enter the definition of " + word + ": ");
        String definition = userInput.nextLine();
        Word *** = new Word(word, POS, definition);
    }
```

I want to name each new Word the actual word itself, instead of the same thing every time I call the method. I searched online but I couldn't find any answers.

Comment: The variable name is just something useful for you to reference in your code. What do you want to do with it? That Word will stop existing as soon as you exit the addWord method.

Comment: Have you learned what `Collections` or arrays are?  I feel like this is only an issue you think of when you haven't learned about either of them.

Comment: I have not learned collections. I am learning array lists now. I want to be able to differentiate between multiple Word objects when I add them in. Basically I'm asking, if I put `Word word1 = new Word(word, POS, definition);` and run the method multiple times and add the new Word to an array list each time, won't they all show up as "word1"?

Answer (score 0):

Not ***possible*** in java.

Why would you wanna do it anyways? You can simply use some sort of a **list** to **save** the newly created Word Objects. The list will allow you to *iterate* and grab the needed info that you desire.

```
String name;
String partOfSpeech;
String definition;
```

Comment: So if I use an array list or something like that, do I have to name the variable before I add it to the list? Since if I run the method multiple times to add multiple Word Objects to the list, they need to have different names each time, right?